# LGTV -WebOS - Is there a way to open an URL on the TV browser?

Tags: webos, lg

I am developing a web hosting app for the LG/TV WebOS.

I know that the web hosting app is basically running inside a browser engine (webkit?).

When the user is about to make the payment (I am using Paypal because I don't like PaymentWall), the app directs the user to the paypal confirmation page where there is no mean for the user to click on the CORFIRM PURCHASE button. I don't see the "mouse" cursor and there is no documentation I could find about the theme.

So, I was thinking if I could launch that payment page on the tv's browser.

That browser has a cursor that moves when I click the arrows.

Any way to do that? To launch an URL from the app into the television browser? or to make the cursor appear inside the app?

Comment: Are you sure the app will be accepted by the LG app QA?  http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-developer-guide/app-purchase/

Comment: why do you say that? The payment is processed by paypal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this approach.

```
openLink(url: string): void {
    webOS.service.request("luna://com.webos.applicationManager", {
        method: "launch",
        parameters: {
            id: "com.webos.app.browser",
            params: {
                target: url,
            },
        },
        onSuccess: (res: any): void => {
            console.log("Browser open success. ", res);
        },
        onFailure: (res: any): void => {
            console.log("Browser open fail. ", res);
        },
    });
}
```

It requires  webOS.js or webOSTV.js library.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use the following library to enhance navigation for web based applications.

https://github.com/luke-chang/js-spatial-navigation

It creates fluid navigation between UI elements using just the arrow buttons.
The user experience is basically identical to that of native applications like Netflix.